# how i can access current user location in fragments using API28?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to access current location in fragments , but i am using API 28 and android version 3.2.1. i try everything from internet follow tutorials but i cant access my current location , there is no error in my code but i don't know why i cant access it. when i run my program i just see google default map, no marker etc.
i want to access my location through network provider as well as gps provider if network provider is not available.
i also add permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

for a permission access i am using library from github and for lacation and map

```
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

please check my code and guide me how i can access current location my code is in below in my code there is also step counter code but ignore that one.

here is my code

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    TextView set_steps;
    TextView set_calories;
    TextView set_distance;
    boolean running = false;
    private static int steps;
    private static int calories;
    private static double distance;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private Marker currentUserLocationMarker;
    private final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
    Provider provider;
    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

        requestLocationPermission();


        stepsCounter();

        locationTracker();


        return view;
    }

    void stepsCounter() {
        set_steps = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.set_steps);
        set_calories = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.set_calories);
        set_distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.set_distance);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        running = true;
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if (countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) getActivity(), countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sensor not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        running = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (running) {

            steps = (int) event.values[0];
            set_steps.setText(steps + "");
            caloriesCounter();
            distanceCover();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    void caloriesCounter() {

        calories = steps / 20;
        set_calories.setText(calories + "");


    }

    void distanceCover() {
        distance = (double) steps * 0.76;
        String distanceText = Double.toString(distance);
        set_distance.setText(distanceText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


    }

  void locationTracker() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            }


        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng= new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str+= addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng= new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str+= addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // Forward results to EasyPermissions
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
    public void requestLocationPermission() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), perms)) {
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Please grant the location permission", REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION, perms);
        }
    }


}
```

but remember i am using ApI 28